# React - How do you call a function from inside another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I had this layout below:

```
class Navigation extends React.Component {
 primaryFun() { console.log('funn') }

 secondaryFun() {
  this.primaryFun();
 }
}
```

I'd of expected this to then call primary but instead I get an undefined, Ok.

So I thought I'd add a constructor to bind the function to this:

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props)
 this.primaryFun = this.primaryFun.bind(this);
}
```

but primary fun is still undefined.

In my real project I'm calling these on a mouseOut event.

Feels like the above should work and tbh the documentation for React is all over the shot so couldn't find much here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this calling one function inside the other

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.mouseClick = this.mouseClick.bind(this);
    this.primaryFun = this.primaryFun.bind(this);
    this.secondaryFun = this.secondaryFun.bind(this);
  }

  primaryFun(){
    console.log('primaryFun funn') 
  }

  secondaryFun(){
    console.log('secondaryFun funn') 
    this.primaryFun()
  }

  mouseClick(){
    this.secondaryFun()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.mouseClick}>   
      Hello World!
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Here when you click on "Hello world" **secondaryFun** is called and inside **secondaryFun** , **primaryFun** is been triggered

Comment: Yes this is the type of fun im talking about

Answer (score 2):

You also need to bind the `secondaryFun` function to use `this` inside that. Without that, the `this` inside the function `secondaryFun` will refers to the function scope which is `secondaryFun`

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind this in your mouseOut

```
onMouseOut={this.secondaryFun.bind(this)}
```

Or a as best practice use the Lambda syntax. It'll bind this for you

```
onMouseOut={()=>this.secondaryFun()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both functions have the correct `this` scope. If you are using class properties, see https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/. Which already present on the babel-preset-react-app used by create-react-app, you can use that and write those as arrow functions, as seen on the babel link. And avoid having to use `.bind` on the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You must bind() both two functions.
You should that:

```
class Navigation extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.primaryFun = this.primaryFun.bind(this);
        this.secondaryFun = this.secondaryFun.bind(this);
    }

    primaryFun() {
        console.log('funn')
    }

    secondaryFun() {
        this.primaryFun();
    }
}
```