# How to call function inside another function in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-native

How to call one function inside another function? Here, both functions are members of same class in react native.

I want to call a one function inside a another function but it's showing me error like `undefined is not a function`

How can i solve this ?

Here my code is:

```js
export default class placeOrder extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     
    };
  }

  
  PayNow(payM){
    console.log(payM);
  }

  CODPayBtn(props)
  {
     let total = props.total;
     let temp = props.temp;
     let charge = props.charge;
     if(total == temp)
     { 
        if(total-charge > 299)
        {
        return(
            <>
            <Button mode="contained" style={{padding:8,backgroundColor:'green',margin:8}} onPress={() => {this.PayNow('COD')}}>
            Cash on Delivery ( ₹{total} )
           </Button>
            
              </>);
          }
          else
          {
              
          }
      }
      else
      {
       
      }

  }


  render(){
  
    return(
      <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView>
      <View>
       <this.CODPayBtn total={this.state.total} temp={this.state.temp} charge={this.state.charge}/>
        
      </View>
      </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
   )
  }
}
```

There is a button in `CODPayBtn()` function and if this button is clicked then I want to call `PayNow()` function but it's giving an error that `undefined is not a function`.

Comment: I think the problem is the "this" keyword. Have you tried just calling PayNow('COD') instead of calling this.PayNow('COD')?

Comment: wan i use only PayNow('COD') it's show me error like  PayNow doesn't exist

Comment: I haven't used the old class-based react syntax in a while. I apologize for getting it wrong. You need to bind() the functions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350217/react-how-do-you-call-a-function-from-inside-another-function

Comment: sir can you explain with example that how can i bind ??

Comment: I've written an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind this to your class functions.

```js
constructor( props ){
    super( props );
    this.PayNow = this.PayNow.bind(this);
    this.CODPayBtn = this.CODPayBtn.bind(this);
  }
```

Or, better, use arrow functions to not have to deal with all that.

```js
CODPayBtn = (props) => {
     let total = props.total;
     let temp = props.temp;
     let charge = props.charge;
     if(total == temp)
     { 
        if(total-charge > 299)
        {
        return(
            <>
            <Button mode="contained" style={{padding:8,backgroundColor:'green',margin:8}} onPress={() => {this.PayNow('COD')}}>
            Cash on Delivery ( ₹{total} )
           </Button>
            
              </>);
          }
          else
          {
              
          }
      }
      else
      {
       
      }

  }
```

This happens because of how `this` works in js. When a function is defined as `function (){..}`, it loses its implicit `this` and it is set to `undefined` in classes. That's why we have to manually bind this to the function. Or use arrow functions that don't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Bind your functions like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };

    this.PayNow = this.PayNow.bind(this);
    this.CODPayBtn = this.CODPayBtn.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<View>
      {this.CODPayBtn(props)}      
</View>
```

Comment: i want to call PayNow() inside CODPayBtn()

Comment: try the es6 syntax:
PayNow = (payM) =>{
    console.log(payM);
  }